# Select specific element from mulitple div tags for click event backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a html template

```
<div class="subtemplate-wrapper">
<div class="cover"></div>
<label>
<span>
Description
<abbr title="required">*</abbr>
</span>
</label>
<textarea required="required"></textarea>
<span class="help-block"> </span>
</div>
```

Also I want to bing an event click on this based on class subtemplate-wrapper.
How do i get which elemt was was clicked ?
I want to later get the access the value of the element clicked.

```
events: {
          'click .subtemplate-wrapper': 'getTextInput'
        },
        getTextInput: function(ev) {
          var clicked_element = $(ev.currentTarget) // does not give me what is clicked !
        },
```

Comment: `$(e.target)` should do what you want.

Comment: Do you want to get the content of textarea?

Comment: @user1716672 - yes i want content of text area

Comment: @FlorianF. - I am a newbie and i want to access the required attribute of text area so how do i do it ?

Comment: answer below but it's not a good idea to have the event binding to the wrapper - when user clicks in the textarea to type, it will execute. You should bind to a button or a div that's not a wrapper

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var $clicked_element = $(ev.target)
```

This will give you the element on which the event has occurred.

And then the usual `$clicked_elemen.val()`

`ev.currentTarget` will always give you the element to which the event was bound, in this case, `<div class="subtemplate-wrapper">`

Also, if you really want a `click` handler ***only*** on the `TextArea`, you should rather have your selector as

```
'click .subtemplate-wrapper textarea': 'getTextInput'
```

than on the wrapper itself.

Comment: `$(ev.currentTarget).find('textarea')` would be another option. Or even `$(ev.target).closest('.subtemplate-wrapper').find('textarea')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    events: {
      'click .subtemplate-wrapper': 'getTextInput'
    },
    getTextInput: function(ev) {
      var clicked_element = $(ev.currentTarget) // does not give me what is clicked !

      console.log('text is ');
      console.log(clicked_element.find('textarea').val());

    },
```

As I commented above, you should not bind to the wrapper because when use clicks in the text area, it will execute. You should bind do something like this:

```
<div class="subtemplate-wrapper">
    <div class="cover"></div>
    <label>
        <span>
            Description
                <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
        </span>
    </label>
    <textarea id="textContent" required="required"></textarea>
    <span class="help-block"> </span>

    <div id="submit">
   Submit
    </div>
</div>


    events: {
      'click #submit': 'getTextInput'
    },
    getTextInput: function(ev) {
      var clicked_element = $(ev.currentTarget) 

      console.log('text is ');
      console.log(clicked_element.parent().find('textarea').val());

    },
```

Comment: I find that `closest(...).find(...)` is almost always more robust than `parent().find(...)`.